# How to restore /lib/libc.so.6?

Tags: linux, restore, sudo, rm, glibc

I occasionally deleted my /lib/libc.so.6.

By using LD_PRELOAD I successfully made a link of my /lib/libc-2.12.1.so file in my home folder and now most of the command works (cp, ln, etc...). But I still can not make a new link in /lib/ because sudo still doesn't work

```
sudo: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object 
file: No such file or directory
```

Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you bypass `sudo` and reboot into a LiveCD. From it, you should be able to copy the file on your main hard disk to its proper location.

If you have no LiveCD access, you could attempt to use `su` and login directly as your root user. This may break as `sudo` has, so this is a bit iffy.

Also, you could attempt to reboot into single user mode (by appending `3` to the kernel's boot options) and login as root directly.

Comment: yeah, that solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Sudo may not work, but what about `su`?

```
$ su
Enter root's password:
# <now you are root>
```

This of course depends on you having set up a root password at some point in the past and you remembering what it is now ;)